# Find and remove columns from array based on another array python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have two .CSV files:

One is a dataset with over 1500 features and 300 samples,

the second is an RFECV ranking of features:
[image: Image showing an example of two files]

I'm trying to remove each column of a feature from the dataset, that does not have a ranking of 1.

So we only should have something like this:

[image]

What would be the proper way of doing something like that in Python?

I was thinking of transposing the second array, finding the indexes with ones and moving columns with these indexes from the dataset to an another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
rank_1 = df2[df2.Ranking == 1].Features
new_df = df1[rank_1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It's exactly how I needed it and way simpler too!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("path-to-first-csv-file.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("path-to-second-csv-file.csv")

result = df1[df2[df2["Ranking"] == 1]["Features"]]
```